# Sync Microsoft Exchange Calendar to Google Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar, google-calendar, google-workspace

Is there any way to sync a Microsoft Exchange Calendar to Google Calendar?

To be clear, I need the information from a calendar on an Exchange server to actually list itself as a calendar on a Gmail account so that it can be synced from Gmail to a phone. This means that sharing the calendar isn't going to work, as the Exchange account would still be the owner of the calendar.

I am open to using server or client-side installations, plugins, anything.

Comment: @user1999298: Did the Sync2 solution work for you? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used Google sync in the past. You install it locally on the desktop and it syncs from Outlook to GCalendar. Unfortunately it has been discontinued and is no longer available.

There are some third-party apps (like [Sync2](http://www.sync2.com/?pcode=803270342ci77)) that are out there but I have not used them. 
There doesn't seem to be a great free option right now with Google sync going away.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2716936
I use it to sync my Outlook (non-exchange) calendar with Gmail which then syncs with my iPhone.

I’ve not tested it with an Exchange calendar but see no reason as to why it won’t work for you.

Is this something you were thinking of?

Comment: It sounds from what you're saying that the calendar's owner is the Google account, and you are just syncing it to Outlook to display it.  I need to have the Google account be the owner of what would essentially be a rolling duplicate of the Exchange calendar.

Isn't it insane the ridiculous hoops these companies make their customers jump through in the name of 'competition'?

Comment: Actually mine is the other way round, I sync changes up to Gcalendar from Outlook.

Comment: With the same software?  I am not so savvy on the behind-the-scenes protocol with Enterprise suites like Outlook or Gapps, so maybe I have a confused idea of where the data is actually stored.  That brings me to a second concern, however, namely that the service you've linked has been disconnected by Google to try and bruteforce a little market share away from Microsoft.

Comment: Google's sync solution has now been discontinued. There is a solution offered by Google specifically for Corporate Apps accounts, but this is likely to not be suitable for most individual users.

Answer (score 2):

This program here seems (on initial testing) to work for me from Exchange to Google Calendar:

http://www.pppindia.com/calendar-sync/index.html

It is limited to syncing within a 30 day range, but as this is so I can see my current meeting schedule on my phone this works fine for me. It allows you to select from your available outlook & google calendars to pick which ones you want to sync, along with which calendar should act as the "master" calendar.

There is a free version with basic sync facilities and a paid for pro version that offers more sophisticated sync rules.